# Unexpected results in Multisim

Tags: mosfet, switches, multisim

I am in the process of selecting a N channel MOSFET for switching purposes and thus, tried out this simple circuit in Multisim. But it seems that the MOSFET conducts in the cut off mode and remains off in the saturation mode. Can you tell me where I might be going wrong?

[image: Simulation/schematic]

Comment: Try adding a series resistor between the drain and ammeter. You are trying to short 5V to GND in this setup.

Comment: Somethings screwed up, probably with your MOSFET SPICE model, but I don't know Multisim so it could be something else (such as the type of ground- it has to be a reference ground). The current should be about 450mA in the first case, and a few nA in the second case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I actually tried adding a resistor but it still shows the same results. What do you think I should do?

Comment: Hello Spehro! But when the MOSFET will be used as a switch in an application it is expected to have 0 A current when its off.

Comment: @BhagyashreeKhairnar There is **always** going to be a bit of leakage when Vds > 0. Nothing is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an issue with your 2N7002 SPICE model. Here are results from three different SPICE models (5V Vds, +4V or -1V gate voltge).

```
          ON             OFF
```

Philips:      201mA          19pA

Fairchild:    385mA          600nA

Zetex:        206mA          833nA

Needless to say, the OFF currents are hardly trustworthy, but it does behave more-or-less as you'd expect. Here's the Philips model for your comparison: `*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
*
.SUBCKT 2N7002/PLP 1 2 3
Cgs  2 3 12.3E-12
Cgd1 2 4 27.4E-12
Cgd2 1 4 6E-12
M1 1 2 3 3 MOST1
M2 4 2 1 3 MOST2
D1 3 1 Dbody
.MODEL MOST1 NMOS(Level=3 Kp=20.78u W=9.7m L=2u Rs=20m Vto=2 Rd=1.186)
.MODEL MOST2 NMOS(VTO=-4.73 Kp=20.78u W=9.7m L=2u Rs=20m)
.MODEL Dbody D(Is=125f N=1.023 Rs=1.281 Ikf=18.01 Cjo=46.3p M=.3423
+            Vj=.4519 Bv=60 Ibv=10u Tt=161.6n)
.ENDS
*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
*`

Comment: Thank you for the reply !I don't know what a SPICE model is ... Can you tell me what changes can I make in the circuit or may be user another simulator to analyse?

Comment: @BhagyashreeKhairnar, a SPICE model is a file used by your simulation program to generate results that would be expected when the circuit is physically realized. Suc parameters are saturation current, size of N-channel, etc.

Comment: But I am getting the same results for other MOSFETs too.

Comment: Can you get your simulator to show the correct value if you substitute a resistor for the MOSFET?